# Create directory on the internal storage in react native expo

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, local-storage

I am using this two functions below in a react native expo project to stock data in a json file and then stock the file on the internal storage. What this code does is that it ask me for permission to stock inside a folder choosed by me and then stock the file inside this folder. But it doesn't create the folder "ProjectName" before creating the file. I have tried a lot of methods but can't create the folder first then the file.
So, what I need is that it creates the folder "ProjectName" then it creates the file inside this folder. Someone got a clue please?

This is the two functions that I've tried :

```
const saveJSONToFile = async (fileName, jsonData, mimetype) => {
        const directory = FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'my-project/';
        const fileUri = directory + fileName + '.json';
        try {
            await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(directory, { intermediates: true });
            await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, JSON.stringify(jsonData));
            console.log('File URI:', fileUri);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error saving JSON data:', error);
        }
        await saveFile(fileUri, fileName, mimetype);
    };
const saveFile = async (uri, filename, mimetype) => {
        if (Platform.OS === "android") {
            const permissions = await FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync();
            if (permissions.granted) {
                const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 });
                await FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework.createFileAsync(permissions.directoryUri+'/ProjectName/', filename, mimetype)
                    .then(async (uri) => {
                        await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(uri, base64, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 });
                    })
                    .catch(e => console.log(e));
            } else {
                await shareAsync(uri);
            }
        } else {
            await shareAsync(uri);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I've passed to the same situation, create the folders when your app startup.
The code below solves my problem. Adapt to your problem and place it before any save attempts

```
  const imageDirectory = fileUtils.getPath('image');
  const videoDirectory = fileUtils.getPath('video');
  const audioDirectory = fileUtils.getPath('audio');
  const cacheDirectory = fileUtils.getPath('cache');
  const documentDirectory = fileUtils.getPath('document');

  const directoryCreateConfig = {
    intermediates: true,
  };

  try {
    const response = await Promise.all([
      FileSystem.getInfoAsync(imageDirectory),
      FileSystem.getInfoAsync(videoDirectory),
      FileSystem.getInfoAsync(audioDirectory),
      FileSystem.getInfoAsync(cacheDirectory),
      FileSystem.getInfoAsync(documentDirectory),
    ]);
    const [image, video, audio, cache, document] = response;
    const directoriesToCreate = [];
    if (!image.exists) {
      directoriesToCreate.push(imageDirectory);
    }
    if (!video.exists) {
      directoriesToCreate.push(videoDirectory);
    }
    if (!audio.exists) {
      directoriesToCreate.push(audioDirectory);
    }
    if (!cache.exists) {
      directoriesToCreate.push(cacheDirectory);
    }
    if (!document.exists) {
      directoriesToCreate.push(documentDirectory);
    }

    await Promise.all(
      directoriesToCreate.map(x =>
        FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(x, directoryCreateConfig),
      ),
    );
  } catch (error) {
    await Promise.all([
      FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(imageDirectory, directoryCreateConfig),
      FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(videoDirectory, directoryCreateConfig),
      FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(audioDirectory, directoryCreateConfig),
      FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(cacheDirectory, directoryCreateConfig),
      FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(
        documentDirectory,
        directoryCreateConfig,
      ),
    ]);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this creates the directory on the cache no ? Because I'm trying to create the directory on the internal storage

Comment: there's some method to help me manipulate path. 'getPath' standardize my folders path.

export const fileFolders = {
  video: 'video',
  image: 'image',
  audio: 'audio',
  cache: 'cache',
  document: 'document',
};
export const getPath = (type: keyof typeof fileFolders) => {
  const folderName = fileFolders[type] || fileFolders.cache;
  const base = folderName === 'cache' ? cacheDirectory : documentDirectory;
  return `${base}${folderName}`;
};

Comment: the cache directory is just for my temp files, they will be deleted when low storage.
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#cachedirectory